# concurrent insert issue in sql 2012 entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, frameworks

I am developing a web application using entity framework, asp 4.5 with sql 2012 as back end.
Actually it is an online examination website. Now the issue is, I have to insert 36 rows to the table (36 Questions for an exam, with answers) once the user finishes the exam. So i have taken all the 36 answers and kept it in a data table and i passed the data table to Stored procedure( and the ID is auto generated) . and then i checked and it is working fine. But the problem is when concurrent transactions are happening( ie, if 10 or more people "Submit" the answers at the same time), only 1 or 2 user's data is inserting  and also sometimes the insert is not happening properly. So how can i do multiple concurrent insert to stored procedure ..?

My Submit button code

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] 
            { new DataColumn("StudentId", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("QuestionId", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Options",typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Point",typeof(int))

            });
            dt.Rows.Add(userid, a[0], RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text, 0);
            dt.Rows.Add(userid, a[1], RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text, 0);
            dt.Rows.Add(userid, a[2], RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text, 0);
            .
```

.......
.... 
dt.Rows.Add(userid, a[35], RadioButtonList36.SelectedItem.Text, 0);

```
            ojclsExam.TableInsert(dt);
```

}

array "a" contains the question Nos.. I am Not considering "Point" now so just passing "0" directly and i have created a user defined table type "dbo.StudAns" in sql server for passing this data table to stored procedure.
Business layer code is

```
  public void TableInsert(DataTable dt)
  {

      var items = new SqlParameter("Paramtable", SqlDbType.Structured);
      items.Value = dt;
      items.TypeName = "dbo.StudAns";
      objExamDBEntities.ExecuteStoreProcedure("spInsertAnswerTable", items);

  }
```

and stored procedure is

```
USE [ExamDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertAnswerTable]
      @tblAnsers StudAns READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO tblStudentAnswer(StudentId, QuestionId, Options,Point)
      SELECT StudentId, QuestionId, Options,Point FROM @tblAnsers
END
```

It is working properly but when it comes multiple simultaneous entries, it is not working.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The ASP.Net / Entity Framework / Sql Server stack should be concurrent-safe if you stick to the path, unless you do interesting things like static `DbContexts` or direct use of Sql `@@IDENTITY` etc. We don't have enough to go on here.

Comment: You mean to say that I should  go with DbContexts ?

Comment: Can you please also show where `objExamDBEntities` is declared - need to ensure this is not `static`